# Active directory based permissions SID, username or email?

Tags: permissions, active-directory, architecture

My application has a table with the permissions to the screen it has. Which of the following should I use to store the permissions against:

- sid
- username
- email
- other

It's in an internal enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but it sounds like you want to grant permissions in your app using AD properties associated with an account the user authenticates with.  If that's correct, you should use the SID as that is the [intended purpose of that property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778824(v=ws.10).aspx), and it is the least likely of the properties to be changed.  A username, an email address, or other account properties can be changed or reassigned, but the SID will remain the same for that object throughout its life in a domain.